# Execute pending queues using batch? Possible?

Tags: 7, cron

I have implemented the Queue API inside `hook_cron`, to do certain update operations on a site:

```
function HOOK_cron() {
  $interval = variable_get('variable_val', 60 * 60 * 24);
  if (time() >= variable_get('cron_next_execution', 0)) {
    variable_set('cron_next_execution', time() + $interval);
    $queue = 'MODULE_queue';
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get($queue);
    $query = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type=:type', array(':type' => 'profile'))->fetchAll();
    foreach ($query as $node_obj) {
      $node = node_load($node_obj->nid);
      $queue->createItem($node);
    }
  }
}
```

where `MODULE_queue` is name of the queue, who's worker callback does some task on the nodes.

At any moment of time I would like the administrators to be able to run the updates manually using batch.
I would like something like this

- Check if there is anything pending in a queue at the moment Admin chooses to manually update, and execute them in batch.
- If not just run a manual batch update.

So, I'm stuck at the part where I need to run the queue inside batch. I am not sure if this even is possible. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer to know "how?" over "is it possible?". I can bet it is, even if I don't exactly know how ;)

Comment: @Mołot There's an answer just below, to answer how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check: https://drupal.org/project/queue_ui

> Process queue with Batch API

Comment: I rolled back the edit previously made. There's no point in copying the project page; I have quoted the *relevant* feature.

Comment: Also you'll require this patch to run system queues via Queue UI module - https://drupal.org/node/700836. Because by default it supports only its own queues.